# Retrieving specific values from subsetting a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` in R thus:

```
my.dt <- data.table(x=seq(1:5),y=(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)))
```

I want to extract a single value, or a vector of values from this:

```
boolean.vector <- my.dt[x<4,"y",with=FALSE]
boolean.value <- my.dt[x<2,"y",with=FALSE]
```

However, these return values are still of class `data.table`. As such, I cannot, for example, do the following:

```
> if(boolean.value) { print("Hello") }
Erro em if (boolean.value) { : argumento não é interpretável como lógico
# (Error in if (boolean.value) { : argument cannot be interpreted as logical)
```

How can I retrieve the raw values so I can use them in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
my.dt[1:3,"y",with=FALSE]
```

I would just do one of:

```
my.dt$y[1:3]
my.dt[["y"]][1:3]
my.dt[x<2, "y"][[1L]]
my.dt[1:3, get(y)]
my.dt[1:3, eval(as.name(y))]
```

In base R `[[` doesn't copy the vector (it's copy-on-change), so this is very efficient and there isn't any need to use `data.table` syntax for this.

Comment: Apologies, this is a case where my minimal code failed to represent the problem. I actually wish to specify a row-selection clause, e.g. my.dt[x < 2,"y",with=FALSE] which doesn't seem to fit your answer. I'll update the question.

Comment: How about sticking `[[1]]` on the end?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `unlist` function to transform the output to a boolean vector:

```
unlist(boolean.value)
   y 
TRUE 

unlist(boolean.vector)
   y1    y2    y3 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```