# how to retrieve, extract value from data frame, then assign to object to be used for indexing

Tags: r, object, indexing, user-input, assign

I am trying to write a function to allow the user to input various parameters ("means", "temp", etc.), which are then compiled into a list so that I can work with them. Values from the list are extracted and assigned to objects.

```
param <- function(){
parameters <- c("means","variance","temp","gene","add") 
x <- list()
for(i in 1:length(parameters)){
  z <- readline(paste("Input ", parameters[i], ": ", sep=""))
  #store inputs in vector x
  x[[z]] <- z
  #x[[i]] <- z
  #x[i] <- z
} #End of for loop to bring in inputs

#Bind results into a vector
y=c(x[[1]],x[[2]],x[[3]],x[[4]],x[[5]])
#Assign answers to proper variable names so they can be used to index.  
means <- y[1]; variance <- y[2]; temp <- y[3]; gene <- y[4]; add <- y[5]
#means <- x[[1]]; variance <- x[[2]]; temp <- x[[3]]; gene <- x[[4]]; add <- x[[5]]
} #End of function to bring in inputs
```

I want to use the objects to index a larger data frame (strn.x).

```
yav=strn.x[NT==temp, means]
```

I've referenced https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-April/158757.html, to learn how to assign user inputs to objects, and I recognize (based on [Retrieving specific values from subsetting a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648651/retrieving-specific-values-from-subsetting-a-data-table)) that part of my problem is the class the objects take on. I've attempted to use "[[" to extract the values without the name, but they still come out as class 'list' or 'data.frame' depending on what I include in the function above.

```
means
 V1
1 FT_mn
class(means)
[1] "data.frame"
```

I'd like them to take on the form:

```
[1] FT_mn
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Currently your function only returns the value for `add`. It is really unclear what you want your function to do with out a reproducible example (at least of what you want). Even better would be a description of why along with what.

Answer (score 0):

Try unlist() to convert a data.frame or list into a vector.